# It is impossible to login to a firebase with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple custom login page, using firebase. Basically there is an admin page where a javascript is checking if current user is authenticated. If not, it will be redirected to a login page, which after authentication will return to the original admin stuff.

this is the script that checks authentication:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
var ref = new Firebase("firebase.linkishere.com ?>");    

var authData = ref.getAuth();
if (authData) {
  console.log("User is authenticated!");
  document.getElementById("container").style.display = "block";
} else {
  var login = "login.php";
  window.location.href = login;
  console.log("I'm not authenticated;")
}
```

and this is the script on the login page:

```
$('#signIn').on("click", function (){ 
var username = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();

  ref.authWithPassword({
  email    : username,
  password : password
  },

  function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case "INVALID_EMAIL":
        errorMessage.innerHTML = "The specified user account email is invalid."
        console.log("The specified user account email is invalid.");
        break;
      case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
        errorMessage.innerHTML = "The specified user account password is incorrect."
        console.log("The specified user account password is incorrect.");
        break;
      case "INVALID_USER":
        errorMessage.innerHTML = "The specified user account does not exist."
        console.log("The specified user account does not exist.");
        break;
      default:
        errorMessage.innerHTML = "Error logging user in"
        console.log("Error logging user in:", error);
    }
    } else {
  console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  window.location.href = "index.php";
  remember: "sessionOnly"
  }
  });
});
```

All this works fine on chrome, firefox, microsoft edge, but for some reason on internet explorer 11, it won't stay authenticated. I enter my details, the firebase accepts it but then it jumps back to the login page, with a console log: I'm not authenticated.

It's like internet explorer won't remember auth state after page refresh, or after it is redirected.

What am I missing?

Comment: internet-explorer is old... Im just saying. Never saw anyone use that these days,,

Comment: I wouldn't touch ie with a stick, but you know...

Answer (score 0):

Well... I have tested the same application on different computers running IE 11, and it was running fine. I'm guessing my own computer had a bad spell on it or something. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've found this exact same problem in IE11, for some reason it seems to be an issue with a firewall and proxy server between the browser and the Firebase servers. Logins fail with a `A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.` error. Oddly enough I could connect to the database side of firebase without any issues. When tracking down the problem, IE doesn't even try and communicate with the Google authentication servers.

After attempting lots of different options the one that worked (it's a bit of a hack) was to place a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />` tag right after the HEAD tag on the HTML pages. When logging in and getting the error, redirect the page to one that has its mode set to IE9 and logs in using query params as per the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/js/shims.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function() {
    var config = {
      apiKey: '<your keys>',
      authDomain: '<your keys>',
      databaseURL: '<your keys>',
      storageBucket: '<your keys>',
      messagingSenderId: '<your keys>'
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
      if (!url)
        url = window.location.href;
      name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
      var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)");
      var results = regex.exec(url);
      if (!results) return null;
      if (!results[2]) return '';
      return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user)
        window.location.replace('/');
      else {
        firebase.auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          getParameterByName('user'), 
          getParameterByName('pass')
        )
        .then(function() {
          window.location.replace('/');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    });

    }());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll note that this will redirect the page when the user has logged in, also you will need to pretty up the page and deal with incorrect passwords etc.

The code to call this page should look similar to:

```
if (err.code === 'auth/network-request-failed') {
  var uri = '/login.html?user='
    + encodeURI(email).replace('@', '%40') + '&pass=' + encodeURI(password);

  window.location.replace(uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is to open a shell whenever you have web tech problems. Open the shell, type in ipconfig flush dns to clear all web related cookies from your browser. Second =You have to go into windows services and scroll down until you find World Wide Web publishing service which allows data trznsactions to outsourced databases that are not associated with windows.. Switch it back on. Your using your Windows to test your web application and you are probably using a server such as xampp or wamp.I'm guessing. When installing these server apps either they will switch it off or you will. IE depends on it for god knows what in some computers or Windows versions. Sadly you will have to off your server, set that servrce to on so IE's security settings don't catch this. Usually xampp is the problem. And without both running you cant test with Firebase. Windows doesn't like Google and at times they clash. Use Chrome or get another server app that uses a vm.

Comment: Oh forgot to mention, if your only using Java without a server you may still need to install the Microsoft 2008 Redistributable package because you will need that World Wide Web publishing service for outsourcing data. Just be sure its on.